# difference between spread operator and without the spread in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just have a question about a piece of code that can be done with the spread operator (`...`) and without the spread operator. But the result stays the same.

```
 exercisesChanged = new Subject<Exercise[]>();
  finishedExercisesChanged = new Subject<Exercise[]>();
  private availableExercises: Exercise[] = [];

fetchAvailableExercises() {
    this.fbSubs.push(this.db
      .collection('avaibeleExercises')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            name: doc.payload.doc.data()['name'],
            duration: doc.payload.doc.data()['duration'],
            calories: doc.payload.doc.data()['calories']
          };
        });
      })
      .subscribe((exercises: Exercise[]) => {
        console.log(exercises);
        this.availableExercises = exercises;
        this.exercisesChanged.next(this.availableExercises);
        console.log(exercises);
      }));
  }
```

So it is about this line:

```
 this.exercisesChanged.next(this.availableExercises);
```

If I just do with the spread operator: `...this.availableExercises` or without. The result doesn't change. So what is the benefit of it then?

And I use it in this component:

```
export class NewTrainingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  exercises: Exercise[];
  exerciseSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private trainingService: TrainingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exerciseSubscription = this.trainingService.exercisesChanged.subscribe(
      exercises => (this.exercises = exercises)
    );
    this.trainingService.fetchAvailableExercises();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well... that's because you're doing nothing with the spread operator, you created a clone of that object. https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator here's a good read on spread operators.

Comment: Ah, oke, thank you for your reply

Comment: ??? why somebody gives this a d vote??? Can you explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain everything to you:
Spread operator will copy all of your object {keys,values} (except some advanced types like symboles) and assign it to a new variable (means a new reference or lets say a **new memory address reference**).
To more clarification: Of course there is a big difference between using spread and without spread operator i will give you an example:
lets say: `this.availableExercises` has a memory address of **0xAABBCCDD** so: 
`this.exercisesChanged.next(this.availableExercises);` ==> this line will pass the **0xAABBCCDD** address to the **.next(..)** method to be handled after by some codes.
but if we use spread operator like: 
`this.exercisesChanged.next({...this.availableExercises});` ==> this will generate a copy of the {keys,values} means a **new object** of your previous **0xAABBCCDD** addressed object, and assign it to a new reference (**new memory address**) like **0x99FF1155**. 
To understand what i meant look at this example:

```
let myOldReference = this.availableExercises; // memory address: 0xAABBCCDD 
this.exercisesChanged.next(myOldReference); // .next(0xAABBCCDD);

let myNewReference = {...this.availableExercises}; // this will generate a copy to a new memory address: 0x99FF115
this.exercisesChanged.next(myNewReference ); // .next(0x99FF115);
```

so that `myOldRefernce !== myNewReference`  because **0xAABBCCDD** is different to **0x99FF115** as **references**. But keep in mind, **this will keep the same {keys, values}** because it's a **copy of keys values**, but with **different memory references**.

That's why you see the same **keys,values**, but in backgroud, it's different **references**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. But in this specific case. Is it then necessary to use the spread operator?  Because  I understand now it returns a new memory address with that means a new reference.

Comment: you are welcome.. in your case it depends on your need: **(1):**  if you want to modify the **origin object**, you have to keep the same reference (memory address) by using **.next(this.availableExercices)**..  **(2) :** if you want to keep the **origin** object as it is, and make a **copy/clone of that object** to perform modification and to keep the origin as it is, you have to use **.next({...this.availableExercices})**.

Comment: also, keep in mind that **.next(..)** method can keep the same passed reference (same address) through all components in the same application, so this can help you to share states, objects between components, services etc.

Comment: @sohaileb. But why people do a d vote on this post?

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Hello bro,  I really have no idea, maybe some people does not have a good experience to deal with questions or to explain to others with a new manner, so they sobatage it like they did for yours and if you ask they will say "duplicated question".. I think, stackoverflow team has to make changes about some rules concerning votes, because some people have to be banned before they d vote others.. To be honest, me too i got sometimes d votes without any reason :/

Comment: @sohaileb Thank you for your clear explanation. Humans like you are the best in the world. You really helped me. And I really appreciate that. So thank you again.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton thank you a lot for your nice words bro ^__^  you are the most welcome :))